# Can I use only one product with multiple subscription plans in paypal

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

I have googled and can't seem to find an answer to my question.

On my site, It has a 'members' area. I offer three different types of subscriptions, monthly, every 6 months and yearly. I have set up three different subscription plans. One for each subscription type.

**My Question**
Can I use only a single product for all three subscription plans? Since the product is access to the 'members' area?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, products for creating plans are not important.